# Invalid keycloak URL error when installing alfresco-dbp with helm in Kubernetes on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, alfresco, helm, keycloak

I'm currently trying to deploy Alfresco Content Services on AWS following [this guide](https://github.com/Alfresco/acs-community-deployment/blob/master/docs/helm-deployment-aws_kops.md). I got as far as to "Creating File Storage for Alfresco Content Services Community" where I have to create an EFS storage using [another guide](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-dbp-deployment#aws). In step 4 "Deploy the DBP" I get an error which I'm not able to resolve. After running

```
helm install alfresco-incubator/alfresco-dbp -f values.yaml \
--set alfresco-infrastructure.persistence.storageClass.enabled=true \
--set alfresco-infrastructure.persistence.storageClass.name="$DESIREDNAMESPACE-sc" \
--namespace=$DESIREDNAMESPACE
```

I get the following error message:

`Error: execution error at (alfresco-dbp/charts/alfresco-process-services/charts/alfresco-infrastructure/charts/alfresco-api-gateway/templates/deployment.yaml:26:24): A valid keycloakURL needs to be set`

Does anyone know where and how I can set the keycloak URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the [values.yaml](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-dbp-deployment/blob/master/helm/alfresco-dbp/values.yaml) of alfresco-dbp

```
global:
  alfrescoRegistryPullSecrets: quay-registry-secret
  keycloak:
    resource: alfresco
    realm: alfresco
    client: alfresco
    url: "https://alfresco-identity-service.REPLACEME/auth"
```

There is **global.keycloak.url** you need to change.

---

It can be either done with

**helm --set global.keycloak.url**

or

**Change the url for valid one in your values.yaml**

---

[There](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-api-gateway/tree/develop/charts/incubator/alfresco-api-gateway) is this api gateway itself.